# Bootstrap Checkbox Issue

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

Can anyone please help me before I go insane? The checkbox is actually the l shape shown below, you can actually click the grey area next to the word Accept to turn the checkbox on and off.

I just want the checkbox to appear on the left and the label text to the right.

[image]

**Form**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "contact-form", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-div-5">
            <label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TitleId, TitleModel.TitleList)
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-div-5">
            <label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SexId, SexModel.SexList)
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-div-5">
            <label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Forename, new { @placeholder = "Forename *", @type = "text", required = "required" })
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-div-5">
            <label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname, new { @placeholder = "Surname *", @type = "text", required = "required" })
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-div-5">
            <label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @placeholder = "Email Address *", @type = "email", required = "required" })
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-div-5">
            <label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @placeholder = "Username *", @type = "text", @pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}", @title = "Your username must have no spaces or special characters and must be at least 6 characters long.", required = "required" })
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-div-5">
            <label>
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @placeholder = "Password *", @type = "password", required = "required" })
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-div-5">
            <label>
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @placeholder = "Confirm Password *", @type = "password", required = "required" })
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-div-5">
            <label class="checkbox inline no_indent">
                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Accept terms and conditions?
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper">
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Register" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="MFReset" class="button"><span>* Required Fields</span>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**CSS**

```
#contact-form div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#contact-form fieldset {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}

contact-form label .checkbox {
color:#15221E;
height:40px;
text-align:left;
width:324px
}

#contact-form select {
  display: block !important;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #e1e3e2;
  color: #acacac;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px !important;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#contact-form select option {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#contact-form label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}
#contact-form .message {
  display: block !important;
  min-height: 251px;
  width: 100%;
}
#contact-form input,
#contact-form textarea {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 7px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: #e1e3e2;
  color: #acacac;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px !important;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#contact-form input {
  height: 37px;
}
#contact-form input:focus,
#contact-form textarea:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
#contact-form .area .error {
  float: none;
}
#contact-form textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 287px;
  resize: none;
}
#contact-form .success {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #e5412a;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 22px;
}
#contact-form .error,
#contact-form .empty {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 2px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 4px 0px 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #f00;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1.27em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#contact-form .message .error,
#contact-form .message .empty {
  bottom: 5px;
}

.checkbox {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-right:40px; line-height:37px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    /*display:none;*/
}
.checkbox:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 37px;
    height: 37px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background: #e1e3e2;
    color: #acacac;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8); 
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkbox:before {
    content: "\2713";
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    font-size: 15px;
}

.checkbox.inline.no_indent,
.checkbox.inline.no_indent+.checkbox.inline.no_indent {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.checkbox.inline.no_indent:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Surely it cant be this hard.

Please, please, help :-)

Comment: can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle..net)?

Comment: Never done one unfortunately.

Comment: No time like the present:) and actually a bootply might be easier for you. Just paste your html and css into appropriate boxes and hit save. Then share the URL with us. Then SO contributors are more likely to put the time in to help you.